# AVPlayer current item played

Tags: avplayer

I am streaming a playlist file to AVPlayer. There are many files in the playlist. How can I get the currently played audio file? Getting the URL only returns the playlist url and not the actual song being played from the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

you can get current item by this property.

```
@interface AVPlayer (AVPlayerItemControl)

/* indicates the current item of the player */
@property (nonatomic, readonly) AVPlayerItem *currentItem;
```